Chapter Formant: CHAPTER 1 -> CHAPTER ONE
The new requirement of my school is CHAPTER 1 -> CHAPTER ONE. I check the .cls file, may I know how to adjust this?
I appreciate your help
% Chapter formatting in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\MakeUppercase{chapter}~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\nopagebreak \\}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{1pc}


Welcome to TeX SE. Which class are you using? Most class have a way to change the \chapter behavior without modifying the cls document.

probably you just need \renewcommand\thechapter{\ifcase\value{chapter}\or one\or two\or three\or four\else ???\fi}  but with no example shown,  impossible to be sure.

Untested:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NWORDS{chapter}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\chapter{other test}

\setcounter{chapter}{153}

\chapter{another test}

\end{document}


This gives "Chapter first", "Chapter second".

Fixed. Thanks for your feedback
